# Create new Date field from string field in mongodb not working

Tags: mongodb

i have a collection with string field that contains date like `"date" : "Feb 20 2015",` and I need to convert this string field to Date object. My query looks like:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
{
    $project : {
        toDate : new Date("$date"),
        foo : "$date",
        moo : new Date("Feb 25 2015")
    }
}
])
```

and this is the result i get:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("56d61033a378eccde8a83550"),
"toDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00"),
"foo" : "Feb 25 2015",
"moo" : ISODate("2015-02-25T00:00:00.000+01:00")}
```

I am confused because it's working with hardcoded String but not with the variable, as you can see with the `moo` field

Comment: you can not use the external function to process the internal document field in the query. this is invalid `new Date("$date"),`.

Comment: what is the format of date in `date` field in your collection? can you show example document that you have in collection

Comment: `db.my_collection` looks like this `{"_id" : ObjectId("56d61033a378eccde8a8354f"), "num" : 1234, "name" : "Test mr. name", "date" : "Feb 20 2015", "result" : "--", "sector" : "Ḧome seller", "address" : { "city" : "Madrid", "zip" : 123, "street" : "TESTSTR", "number" : 123 } }`

Comment: it is really hard to do this in query because month name is in string, and if we do in query it will perform low, so I don't recommend you to do this in process in query, I recommend you to store valid date type date.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
{
    $project : {
       date: { 
           $dateFromString: {
               dateString: "$date",
           }
       }
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what in needed